# Stop Windows 10 Firewall From Asking For Admin Rights To Run Unknown Apps

Tags: windows, firewall

one of the supplier for my company use the Software called "LogMeIn Rescue" to access the PCs of my company's employees. The problem is that everytime they launch the Software, the PC want the Administrator Permission for allowing the access:

"Windows Firewall has blocked some features of this program." ---> "Allow Access".

The problem now is that all the users in my company don't have the Administrator Privilige but only the Standard one, this means that when they run this program for the first timem, someone have to go there and use the admin user to "Allow Access" so the Software will be accepted on the Windows Firewall.

There is a policy or maybe something else that can avoid this problem for this specific Software? Make sure that it will stop to asking for admin privileges every time it is launched by all users or maybe whitelist it on all windows firewall of the company??

Thank you in advance

Comment: [Just add this program to the whitelist in Windows Firewall, domain-wide, via *GPO*.](http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2010/07/how-to-manage-windows-firewall-settings-using-group-policy/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Group Policy to configure Windows Firewall to allow that kind of traffic;  Windows Firewall will then not need to request user permissions.

This article should help: https://help.logmein.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/How-do-I-configure-my-firewall-to-work-with-LogMeIn-en1.